# Update customer address attribute in Magento via upgrade script

Tags: magento

I would like to know how to update the customer address attribute in Magento via an installation/upgrade script - in particular the `Input Validation` dropdown and the `Maximum Text Length` field.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: you say customer **address** attribute, but in your screenshot it's a customer attribute

Answer (score 3):

In your `config.xml` you have to indicate the Model used for your module setup:

```
//inside <global> node
<resources>
    <stackoverflow_question_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>StackOverflow_Question</module>
            <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
    </stackoverflow_question_setup>
</resources>
```

The setup script:

```
<?php
/* @var $installer Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup */
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$data = array(
    'input_validation' => 'alpha',//see the values of the input validation dropdown to find out what you can put in here
    'max_text_length' => 456
);
$serializedData = serialize($data);
$installer->updateAttribute('customer_address', 'firstname', 'validate_rules', $serializedData);
$installer->endSetup();
```